# Touchpad Stopped Working After Hibernate

Tags: touchpad, hibernate, input-devices

I used the command `pm-hibernate` to see if my notebook would successfully resume after hibernating. Upon resume it went through the BIOS screen, I had to reselect Ubuntu from the Grub menu, but then it went back into the desktop right were I left off, it seemed fine except the touchpad didn't work. I rebooted, and the touchpad still didn't work. `x-input --list` did not list a touchpad, only "Virtual core pointer" with "Virtual core XTEST pointer" listed under that. A mouse plugged into the USB port worked just fine. After another reboot or two, I went into recovery mode and selected the `repair broken packages` option, however it would not initialize the wireless adapter to get a network connection so it would not repair any packages. I explicitly told it to set up the network connection by selecting the option "Use Network Connection", which also failed to do anything, so so then I did what any normal person would do, I shut my system down and went to sleep thinking about that one printer scene from Office Space...

When I woke up this morning, I booted into Recovery Mode again, couldn't really think of anything to do so I told it to start Ubuntu normally, and lo and behold my touchpad is back. I rebooted to make sure it would work booting from Grub and not just from the Recovery Console and it still works. Now `xinput --list` shows `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` plain as day, and everything is working fine, multitouch, gestures, the whole shebang.

So what's the deal? Does anybody have a clue what happened? Is there a way I can figure out what happened, or a specific approach I can take in the future should the problem reoccur?

Answer (score 1):

If your hardware is incompatible with the standard Ubuntu pm-hibernate, you might want to check out [TuxOnIce](http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/).  That is a very sophisticated hibernation program with its **[own PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ppa)**.

**That being said:** ***you should never install a PPA because someone told you so*** (including me) until you've done some research and made a sound, personal judgement as to [what the risks are](http://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/).

You should also remember that a 1000+ user like **[tuxonice](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ppa)** recommended by 1000s of users is more likely (but not surely) safer then the 15-user [ppa.maffia.ru/botnet/ppa/ubuntu](http://www.howdonkey.com/pics/65/make-a-fake-rip-in-wallpaper-for-a-prank.jpg).