# Synpatics Touchpad occasionally not detected

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics

I have Ubuntu 15.04 (kernel 3.19.0-26-generic) on a [Gigabyte P25 W v2](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5054#sp) that sporadically does not appear to detect the touchpad at boot. USB mouse will always work fine.

The input device, when it is working:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event8 
B: PROP=9
B: EV=b
B: KEY=6420 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800011000003
```

The [Synaptics troubleshooting steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) on the Community Wiki did not address my problem. I have posted the [detailed data to github](https://github.com/j-devil/bugs/tree/master/touchpad) from `dmesg` and the `Xorg.0.log` both when the touchpad was working and when it wasn't, and the results of `diff`ing each pair from the [debugging steps](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) also found on the Community Wiki.

This was also an issue on Trusty which I posted a [couple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575488/touchpad-stopped-working-after-hibernate) times [previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575585/touchpad-not-detected-when-usb-hdd-plugged-in-at-boot) and gave up quickly because I was inexperienced so it was more of a PLEASE HELP! rant. Please note the issue is not in fact related to hibernate or any peripherals. This machine has also had Xorg issues on Debian with the discrete **NVIDIA 870M** but finding the pointing device was not an issue on the Debian stack.

I'm hoping it ends up being an X issue but I need some direction on what to do next. If it does end up being a kernel issue I will submit a bug report. Unless I should anyway? I'm still learning how that works as well, but in any case, thank you for your time.

Comment: same kernel, same issue, same touchpad.. Couldn't figure out the problem yet.

Comment: What about your graphics configuration does your notebook have a discrete gpu or just on chip?

Comment: No, I don't have a separate gpu